# Ошибка Cause exception while getting updates при запуске телеграм бота aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Ошибка

```
Updates were skipped successfully.
Cause exception while getting updates.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 381, in start_polling
    updates = await self.bot.get_updates(
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/bot/bot.py", line 110, in get_updates
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_UPDATES, payload)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/bot/base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 119, in check_result
    exceptions.ConflictError.detect(description)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/utils/exceptions.py", line 140, in detect
    raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.TerminatedByOtherGetUpdates: Terminated by other getupdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
```

P.S. Это значит что запущено 2 экземпляра бота. В моем VSCode был запущен дебаг поэтому вылезала ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш бот одновременно запущен сразу в двух программах/на двух устройствах (Например, в pycharm и консоли windows)

Варианты решения:

1. Попробуй-те закрыть что-то одно из этого.
   Если это не помогло:
2. Создайте новый токен бота в BotFather

---

<kbd>[Источник](https://qna.habr.com/q/1041288)</kbd>